# Jinja not imported when executing script from another one

Tags: python, cgi, jinja2

I have a web server with CGI script calling python scripts.
When i try to execute in a main file (test1.py) another script called via

os.system('/var/www/cgi-bin/readIRtemp.py '+arg1+' '+arg2+' '+arg3)

I get his error message in /var/log/apache2/error.log :

```
import: not found
from: can't read /var/mail/jinja2
```

this is understandable for me since when called directly from the python console my script works !

its content is:

```
import sys, os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, select_autoescape

last20values=sys.argv[1]
currTempInDegreesCelcius=sys.argv[2]
print('test '+last20values+' '+currTempInDegreesCelcius)

env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader('/var/www/html/templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)
template = env.get_template('IR.html')
updatedTemplate=template.render( arrayOfTemp = last20values, currTemp=currTempInDegreesCelcius)
Html_file=open("/var/www/html/IR.html","w")
Html_file.write(updatedTemplate)
Html_file.close()
```

I read somewhere something like maybe when calling os.system() the script is running with a different user account or some crazy things like that ... please help!

of course i chmod 777 * everything but that doesnt help ...

Comment: Those are bash errors; your script is not being interpreted as Python. But why are you using CGI for this?

Comment: because it's a little web server, and CGI is for me the most convenient way

Comment: i dont understand why os.system('/var/www/cgi-bin/flaskJinjaUpdateScript.py '+str(last20values)+' '+str(c)) would not work ? (flaskJinjaUpdateScript contains the above code)

Comment: this kind of thing does work for my os.system('/var/www/cgi-bin/readIRtemp.py '+arg1+' '+arg2+' '+arg3)

Comment: Because you don't have anything - such as a hashbang - to tell the OS to run this script via Python rather than bash. But, again, why are you calling it via `os.system` rather than making it a function which you import and call from the first script?

Comment: well this was initially because of the CGI is waiting for the script to end even though i create a fork

Comment: which i had when directly puttin the code of flaskJinjaUpdateScript in my readIRtemp.py (which is successfully called via an os.sys())

Comment: in fact the problem is now that it cant find my modules when i try to simply import :,((( i get error such as ImportError: No module named ... sorry it's just desesperating haha